# Overloaded function of parameters reference to const char array and const char pointer ambiguous

Tags: c++

Look at this code snippet:

```
void fn(const char *s) { }
void fn(const char (&s)[4]) { }

int main() {
    fn("bla");
}
```

This code doesn't compile, as call of `fn` in `main` is ambiguous. Why is that? According to the C++14 standard (2.14.5/8), `"bla"`'s type is *array of n const char*, so I'd expect that the second `fn` will be called.

Can I achieve somehow that I can differentiate between compile-time strings and `const char *`, so a different version of `fn` will be called (in a way, that for compile-time strings, I have the length of the string)? Like using this (this doesn't work, as `fn(const char *)` will be used):

```
template <std::size_t S>
void fn(const char (&s)[S]) { }
```

Comment: On the other hand remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, in this case a `const char *`. Both alternatives are equally valid.

Comment: Please see the duplicate; I believe it will answer all your questions. But if not then let me know and I'll reopen.