# Rationale for overloading C-String and char pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The following program displays 1. It seems completely unnatural to me. Do you know the reason behind this decision? How do you circumvent this problem, especially if you want to provide a constructor which can take both `const char (&s)[n]` and `const char* s`.

```
template <int n>
int f(const char (&s)[n]) {
  return 0;
}

int f(const char* s) {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << f("hello") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It's too bad, because you end up defining a constructor for string class with : `const char*`. Using that, the program must compute the length of the C-string at run-time which is a waste of time. On my own class, it takes `3ns` to initialize a string with `const char (&s)[n]` and `20ns` to initialize a string with `const char*`.

PS: This question is not the same as "What is array decaying?". First, we are in C++ here where the standard says:

*An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.*

which is by the way very fuzzy (can is not very precise). All I want to know is the rationale behind it.

Comment: Are you asking us to read the coders mind? And that's not "overloading strings" or something like that, there's no constructor here, and so on. You just don't understand the code.

Comment: I want to understand why such a decision has been made in the standard. Because, it makes the usage of `const char (&s)[n]` extremely difficult. And I don't see the advantage of it.

Comment: @user0042 : I am not asking : what is array decaying ? I want to know why it is decayed when a better overload seems obvious.

Comment: Anyways, your "[n]" in the template version is **not** the string length. It's (at best, if not decayed etc.) the array length, which can be longer,.That's your answer why a std::string constructor isn't using that to calculate the string length (I think you wanted to ask that)

Comment: Good question. I would have expected the output to be `0`.

Comment: It's a template issue. Indeed, `int f(const char (&s)[6])` is ambiguous.

Comment: @deviantfan The point is that the template would allow getting the length of a string literal at compile time (but maybe the intrinsic `strlen` does that anyway.)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43732803/8157187

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, but luckily std::string can take non-literal values too.

Comment: @deviantfan So what? It could have had a template constructor deducing the length of the literal at compile time, if the output of the above code had been 0.

Comment: (btw., changing the question 10 times doesn't help)

Comment: @deviantfan: I have changed it to acknowledge and reply to the criticism. I believe that presented that way, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I acknowledge the duplicate now with the new reference

Comment: Indeed, even `std::is_same` says they are not the same type. The standard says _Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration._ § 2.14.5.

Comment: @Benoit Here is particular catch that overload   masks the template. if both functions were non-template or they both are  templates, that would be ambiguous call , because array is allowed to decay. To disallow it would broke whole legacy syntax of array and cause way more problems than benefits.

Comment: @InsideLoop: maybe you can achieve the same performance with constexpr functions (I've asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541997/overloaded-function-of-parameters-reference-to-const-char-array-and-const-char-p) recently, and I was able to achieve the same functionality with constexpr functions)

Comment: I got that from the linked answer. But i'm a little bit loss on why the type a string literal is an array reference when the standard says it's an array https://godbolt.org/g/XCPeuU

Comment: @geza: I have tried that. Using constexpr works perfectly with clang (Apple LLVM 8.0.0) but does not work with g++ 7.1.0 nor icpc 2017.0.4. It's too bad.

Comment: Should I open another question then ?